# Desired State Configuration - System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

Tags: release-management, ms-release-management, dsc

I am getting this error while configuring my RM build. The build succeeded 3 times before failing and displaying the error in the title with the error log as follows:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Common.Helpers.OperationFailedException: Failed to apply configuration in the DSC script to the computer. Consult the Logs below for details of the error.
FullyQualifiedErrorId :MI RESULT 1
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.PowershellExecutor.Invoke(String errorContextMessage, Boolean writeResultToLog)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.DeploymentService.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<ApplyDscMofIfScriptIsDsc>b__1d()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.RetryExecutor.Execute(Action action)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.DeploymentService.RunPowerShellScripts(DeploymentMachineSpecification deploymentMachine, ScriptSpecification scriptSpecification, ScriptSpecification initializationScriptSpecification, String applicationPath, IPowerShell powerShellSession)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.EnvironmentProvider.OnPrem.Implementation.OnPremDeploymentProvider.ReadDeploymentResponse(DeploymentResponse response)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.EnvironmentProvider.OnPrem.Implementation.OnPremDeploymentProvider.<CopyBuildsLocally>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.EnvironmentProvider.OnPrem.Implementation.OnPremDeploymentProvider.<RunScript>d__0.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.MonitorServices.Dsc.OnPrem.OnPremDeploymentActions.InvokePlatform(String activityId, MachineSpecification machineSpecification, StorageSpecification storageSpecification, String scriptPath, String configurationPath)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.DeploymentAgent.Services.Deployer.Dsc.DscComponentInstaller.InvokeMethodByReflection(String methodArguments)
```

Comment: Terminology note: There's no such thing as an "RM build" -- builds and releases are totally separate entities. That said, did you look at the log file that's attached to every failed release? Did you look at the event log on the machine where the deployment failed?

Comment: The above is from the event log file from the deployment server. The last few builds have the same error.

Comment: This error message/stack trace does not contain the actual underlying failure, can you please paste the complete error message from the deployment logs of your release?